# How to solve this equation with $x$ both in the numerator and in the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am very rusty in solving equations. How do I solve this one:
$$\frac{71,878 + x}{ 240,022 + x}=0.3141$$

Comment: Hint. Multiply both sides by the denominator on the left.

Comment: Subtract 0.3141 from both sides, then add the two fractions. You get a fraction equal to zero. Therefore the numerator must be zero and the denominator different from zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multipying both sides of the equation we have
$$71,878+x=0.3141(240,022+x)$$
multiplying out
$$71,878+x=75,390.9102+0.3141x$$
$$3,5129102=-0.6859x$$
$$x = -5.121560694$$
and the denominator isn't Zero for this $x$

Comment: Why not just a hint, and let the OP do some of the work and learn a little more? You should not waste your time on the arithmetic. But if you do, you should at least finish with the division.

Comment: Note to the OP: When one multiplies by the denominator there is one more step that should be done. You need to check that the solution(s) found don't make that denominator vanish.